# Cannot Get Two-Column Multiselect to Populate on Edit of Existing Record from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, coldfusion, multi-select

The architecture in use is MVC in OO Coldfusion.
When trying to edit an existing record the record should populate the form when called. All of form fields are populating as expected except for a two-column multiselect ("dealers") which is retrieving data via AJAX. There is another two-column multiselect ("territories") on the form which populates as it should; however, it is retrieving data via a query call to the controller. The "dealers" multiselect is making an AJAX call using the data retrieved by the "territories" as parameters for its AJAX call.
The AJAX is returning the expected data. Using jQuery I cannot get it to populate the multiselect columns at all.

I have logged each step of the AJAX call and verified the data being returned to correct through the entire function.
Where it fails is within the if/else of the for loop. I can see in the console log the results and they are being correctly represented in the correct "if" or "else" blocks of the "for". They just won't display in the multiselect columns when trying to append using jQuery.
There are no JavaScript, jQuery, or Coldfusion errors being returned or displayed. The only thing I can think of is that the "dealers" multiselects are somehow being cleared, but after commenting out anything I've found that could be a culprit I still am not able to get the data to populate the multiselects.
I'm completely stumped.

**UPDATE**: This issue apparently only occurs in Chrome (v75.0.3770.100, 64-bit) as I tried to reproduce in Firefox Developer Edition (v68.0b12, 64-bit) and the code worked as expected.
Still looking for any help or insight as I cannot find anything specific regarding issues with Chrome related to multiselects.

```
function getDealers(territoryIDArray) {
  console.log(territoryIDArray);
  clearMultiSelect($('#dealer-select'));
  var territoryData = territoryIDArray.join(',');
  var $dealerData = $('#selectDealerIDs');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/WebServices/dealerRetriever.cfm',
    data: {
      territoryID: territoryData
    }
  })
  .done(function(results, status, xhr) {
    // console.log(results);
    var data = JSON.parse(results);
    var mycolumns = data.COLUMNS;
    var mydata = data.DATA;
    if ((typeof(mycolumns) == 'object') && (typeof(mydata) === 'object')) {
      if (data.ROWCOUNT === 0) {
        $dealerData.find('option').remove().end();
        $('#selectDealerIDs, #selectDealerIDs_to, #selectDealerIDs_rightAll, #selectDealerIDs_rightSelected, #selectDealerIDs_leftAll, #selectDealerIDs_leftSelected').prop('disabled', true);
        $dealerData.append('<option>NO DEALERS ASSOCIATED WITH</option><option>THE SELECTED TERRITORIES.</option><option>PLEASE SELECT ANOTHER</option><option>OR ADDITIONAL TERRITORIES</option>');
      } else {
        $dealerData.find('option').remove().end();
        $('#selectDealerIDs, #selectDealerIDs_to, #selectDealerIDs_rightAll, #selectDealerIDs_rightSelected, #selectDealerIDs_leftAll, #selectDealerIDs_leftSelected').removeAttr('disabled');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
          console.log($dealerData); // successful
          if (selectedDealerIds.length == 0 || selectedDealerIds.indexOf(mydata.DealerID[i].toString()) == -1) {
              console.log("In 'if': " + mydata.DealerID[i] + ", " + mydata.AccountNumber[i] + ": " + mydata.BusinessName[i] + ", " + mydata.BusinessCity[i]); // successful
              $($dealerData).append('<option class="dealerFrom_edit" value="' + mydata.DealerID[i] + '">' + mydata.AccountNumber[i] + ': ' + mydata.BusinessName[i] + ', ' + mydata.BusinessCity[i] + '</option>');
          } else {
              console.log("In 'else': " + mydata.DealerID[i] + ", " + mydata.AccountNumber[i] + ": " + mydata.BusinessName[i] + ", " + mydata.BusinessCity[i]); // successful
           $('#selectDealerIDs_to').append('<option class="dealerTo_edit" value="' + mydata.DealerID[i] + '">' + mydata.AccountNumber[i] + ': ' + mydata.BusinessName[i] + ', ' + mydata.BusinessCity[i] + '</option>');
          }
        }
      }
    } // end if
  }); // end success
}
```

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to read your Spaghetti code. Your variables are unknown to us readers and you did not include any HTML. Start isolating the issue by retrieving/processing data first and manipulating the DOM second (make use of functions!). Then use the inline debugger in Chrome to check the state for each step.